# Sticky Footer (not sticking!)

Tags: css, sticky-footer

A novice coder here. I've been trying to implement a sticky footer onto my site, but it's simply not working. Basically, it is an image, with some text positioned absolutely on it. Here's my site: http://mc-airlines.hostei.com

As you can see, it's definitely not working!

I'm using this: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/ to do it. Here's the code relevant to the footer on my site:

```
* {
margin: 0;
}

body, html {
text-align:center;
border-width: 0px; 
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
}


#container{
position:relative;
margin: 0 auto -175px;
width:960px;
min-height:100%;
height: auto !important;
text-align:left;
}

#footer{
margin: 0 auto;
text-align:left;
width:960px;
height:175px;
}


#links {
font-family: 'HelveticaNeueRegular', Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif;
color:white;
font-size: 18px;
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 23px;
left: 0;
width: 300px;
}

#links2{
font-family: 'HelveticaNeueRegular', Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif;
color:white;
font-size: 18px;
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
left: 310px;
width: 420px;
}
```

And my html:

```
<div id="container">

<!-- (site content -->

<div class="push"></div>

</div>

<div id="footer">

<img src="images/footer.png" alt="footer" class="foot"/>

<div id="links">
<script type="text/javascript">copyright=new Date();
update=copyright.getFullYear();
document.write("&copy "+ update + " MC Airlines");</script><br>
<span class="psmall">
All content on this site belongs to MC Airlines and its subsidiaries, and may not be used without prior permission from Mr MC. Just kidding, he probably won't reply - just don't abuse it too much :) </span>
</div>

<div id="links2">
Other Links <br>
<span class="psmall">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="">Our Partners</a><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="">MC Airlines Thread</a><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="">MC Airlines Wiki</a><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="">Cyber Airlines</a><br></span>
<span class="pxsmall">
We can not be held responsible for the content on external sites. I mean c'mon, that's just unfair.
</span>
</div>

<!-- #footer close -->        
</div>
```

If anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong I'd be very grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sticky footer is not working because you are using `position:absolute` to layout your page and the footer does not know where to position itself in your document. A quick fix would be to position your footer absolutely as well, e.g.

```
#footer {
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 -480px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1400px;
}
```

But what i would actually recommend is to position your `divs` correctly and use floats instead of `position:absolute`, this will fix all problems that will arise from using such a layout and will be semantically correct.

Comment: oh, well that's disappointing! I guess I've learnt a lesson and will think twice before making layouts in the future. Thanks for your response

Comment: @user1208010 if it works, it works, that has always been the rule. But is it right? that is the question. You can easily fix your layout with a little bit of work, but you have to let your divs flow with the document naturally instead of forcing them to comply. So, replace all those `position:absolute` declarations you have, they don't flow with your document, and use `floats` instead.

Comment: I'm rewriting my layout now. At least I noticed it now instead of much later on in development :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code does not match the site you linked to. My comments are based upon your link, not the code you posted here.

1. Move the footer outside the `#container` div.
2. Add the `.push` div to the bottom of the `#container` div (where the footer is now)
3. add the css rules for `#footer` and `.push` to `clear: both;`

Comment: Hmm, that's strange, I definitely added those things...perhaps my edits didn't save or something :S Anyway thanks for your speedy and helpful response, I'll try it now!

Comment: um, well I checked and i do indeed have all of those things in my code, I added the `clear: both;` to my #footer and .push in css, however it still doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Quick hint...I am not able to see this code in your source HTML

```
<div class="push"></div>
```

This is important cause it helps to stick the footer to the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to do sticky footers that takes a little less code and is more clear on how it works. Take a look at the tutorial at http://www.htmltutorialsandtips.com/css-sticky-footer to see how it works. It will take you through it step by step so you understand how sticky footers work and can then modify your code accordingly. That way you'll be able to apply the concept to any layout instead of just having an answer for this one question.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll keep it bookmarked for future sites!